# Retrieve value of button angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, buttonclick

I'm creating a cross platform app using phonegap and angularjs targeting it for Android Devices.
I don't know how can I retrieve values from a button, for example:

```
<button ng-click="add()" id="add" value="{{prenotation}}">add</button>
```

and in javascript I use:

```
angular.element("#add").val();
```

but returns always the same value (the first).
How can I retrieve the value of the button that I click??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the event along with the ng-click method like:

```
<button ng-click="add($event)" id="add" value="{{prenotation}}">add</button>
```

The event knows what element was used on:

```
 $scope.add = function(event){
    var element = angular.element(event.toElement);
    console.log(element.val());
}
```

Comment: in this way I can save and use the value of the element?

Comment: this works. ill add it to the answer
       
        var element = angular.element(event.toElement);
        console.log(element.val());